# Full calendar not loading the events it is being passed - no errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion, fullcalendar

I've just been following the basic demo for setting up full calendar to pull results from a json feed but it is not showing any of the events it is being passed. I am not getting any javascript errors in my firefox console either.

The calendar itself is initialising, i can jump through different months, but the events simply don't show.

my initialisation code is:

```
...
function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,

            events: "/custom/customtags/plugin/eventmanager/eventService.cfc?method=getEventsJSON&returnFormat=json",

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }                           

        });
...
```

Firefox console is showing the following results to the get json request:

```
[{"START":"2012-02-09","END":"2012-02-29","ID":1,"URL":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/","TITLE":"The great lunch time buffalo"},{"START":"2012-03-01","END":"2012-03-31","ID":3,"URL":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/","TITLE":"Mega Sleep"},
{"START":"2012-03-08","END":"2012-03-08","ID":4,"URL":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/","TITLE":"Breaky"},
{"START":"2012-02-09","END":"2012-02-29","ID":5,"URL":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/","TITLE":"Lunch Time Sudoku"},
{"START":"2012-03-01","END":"2012-03-31","ID":9,"URL":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/","TITLE":"rock n roll rollercoaster sandcastle"}]
```

I am including:

- Jquery 1.7
- Jquery ui 1.8
- full calendar css files
- full calendar js file

How do I debug this? I can't see that it is doing anything different to the various examples I have copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all your key names are in caps, javascript is case sensitive

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to solve the issue of coldfusion automatically capitalising its structure key names. It won't show until its peer reviewed though.   Such a simple solution to something that has been irritating me all afternoon. *hits head*

Comment: understand.. never figured out myself why CF does that either

Comment: Btw: you can lowercase your keynames like this: `<CFSET mystruct['mykey'] = "myvalue" />` that equals to `<CFSET mystruct.mykey = "myvalue" />` but in lowercase.